# React Native doesn't trigger useEffect when updating data (Screen isn't rerendered)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, react-hooks

I'm stuck at a problem - I'm building a receipes app with Firebase Realtime. I've a working prototype, but I'm stuck with an issue where useEffect won't trigger a reload after editing the array [presentIngredients].

This how my presentIngredients is defined (note that presentIngredient is used to store the current user input before the user adds the ingredient. After that, the presentIngredient get's added to the presentIngredients!):

```
const [ presentIngredients, setPresentIngredients ] = useState([]);
const [ presentIngredient, setPresentIngredient ] = useState('');
```

My useEffect hook looks like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect called!')
    return onValue(ref(db, databasePath), querySnapshot => {
      let data = querySnapshot.val() || {};
      let receipeItems = {...data};
      setReceipes(receipeItems);
      setPresentIngredients(presentIngredients);
    })
  }, [])
```

Here's my code to render the UI for adding/removing existing ingredients:

```
{ /* adding a to-do list for the ingredients */ }
<View style={styles.ingredientsWrapper}>
  {presentIngredients.length > 0 ? (

    presentIngredients.map((key, value) => (


        <View style={styles.addIngredient} key={value}>
          <Text>{key} + {value}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeIngredient(key)}>
            <Feather name="x" size={24} color="black" /> 
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    ))
  ) : (
    <Text style={styles.text}>No ingredients, add your first one.</Text>
  )}

  <View style={styles.addIngredientWrapper}>
    <TextInput 
      placeholder='Add ingredients...'
      value={presentIngredient}
      style={styles.text}
      onChangeText={text => {setPresentIngredient(text)}}
      onSubmitEditing={addIngredient} />

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addIngredient()}>
      <Feather name="plus" size={20} color="black" />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>

</View>
```

And this is my function to delete the selected entry from my presentIngredients array or add one:

```
  // update the ingredients array after each input
  function addIngredient() {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    setPresentIngredients(presentIngredients => [...presentIngredients, presentIngredient]);
    setPresentIngredient('');
  }

  // remove items by their key
  function removeIngredient(id) {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    // splice (remove) the 1st element after the id
    presentIngredients.splice(id, 1);
    setPresentIngredients(presentIngredients);

  }
```

The useEffect hook isn't triggered when adding an ingredient, however the change is instantly rendered on the screen. If I delete an item, the change isn't noticeable until I reload the screen - what am I doing wrong?

Note that all this is happening before data is send to Firebase.

Comment: I've tried removing the [] as a second argument from useEffect(), which works, but results in useEffect() getting called every single frame - which can't be good for performance, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

There are a few overt issues I see with the code:

1. The code uses the array index as the React key, so if you mutate the array, i.e. add, remove, reorder, etc... the index values won't be the same as they were on a previous render cycle per array element. In other words, the React key is the same regardless what value is now at any given index and React likely bails on rerendering.
2. The `removeIngredient` callback handler is mutating the existing state instead of creating a new array reference.

## Solution

Using the array index as a React key is bad if you are actively mutating the array. You want to use React keys that are intrinsically related to the data so it's "sticky" and remains with the data, not the position in the array being mapped. GUIDs and other object properties that provide sufficient uniqueness within the data set are great candidates.

```
presentIngredients.map((el, index) => (
  <View style={styles.addIngredient} key={el.id}>
    <Text>{el.key} + {index}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeIngredient(el.id)}>
      <Feather name="x" size={24} color="black" /> 
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
));
```

Use `Array.prototype.filter` to remove an element from an array ***and*** return a new array reference.

```
function removeIngredient(id) {
  Keyboard.dismiss();
  setPresentIngredients(presentIngredients => presentIngredients.filter(
    el => el.id !== id
  ));
}
```

Note above that I'm assuming the `presentIngredients` data element objects have a GUID named `id`.

### Listening for state updates

> The `useEffect` hook isn't triggered when adding an ingredient, however
> the change is instantly rendered on the screen.

The single `useEffect` only exists to run once when the component mounts to fetch the data and populate the local state. If you want to then issue side-effects when the state updates later you'll need a second `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the state to issue the side-effect.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("presentIngredients updated", { presentIngredients });
  // handle side-effect like updating the fire store
}, [presentIngredients]);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer, much appreciated! It does work, but it removes all ingredients - I assume that's because I don't have a GUID - which is probably because I'm using a simple array rather than an object for the ingredients, right? I was looking into switching to a custom object, is there a common way of creating and assigning a GUID when creating objects?

Comment: @mr-woodapple Yeah, see the note in my answer about assuming the data has a GUID. If the data doesn't already have an id type property that you could use then it's common to use a library to generate GUIDs for you and you add an `id` property to your data prior to saving it into local state. [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) are two such packages I have used. Do you need an example for this process?

Comment: That would be great, yes! Creating my IDs before was handled by Firebase, so never had to do this. ^^

Comment: @mr-woodapple Are they no longer handled/generated by Firebase? Can you share which state is populated from Firebase?

Comment: They are, but when I'm trying to delete ingredients, that happens before I send this data to Firebase. It's a screen to create a new receipe, and my goal is to allow the user to delete ingredients he just added (for whatever reason). The only state that's populated by Firebase is the overall `receipeItem` object. I can show that if it helps?

Comment: @mr-woodapple Ah, ok, I see now.... that makes a bit more sense. I thought you were working with and editing data that had been fetched from Firebase and were trying to synchronize. Can you edit the post to show more of *that* user flow, just so it's clear exactly what is interacted with in the UI and what state is updated when adding/removing specific ingredients?

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to make that clear. Nevertheless, I did changed the ingredients to be an object, which include an ID. I used uuidv4, which was super easy! :) And boom, everything works. Many thanks for your help, you're my hero for today! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248055/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-mr-woodapple).

Answer (score 0):

you need to create another useEffect, because the first useEffect need to be called only once (because you are setting a watcher).

```js
useEffect(() => {
   // this effect will be executed when presentIngredients change 
}, [presentIngredients]);
```

if you don't remember how the array of dependencies work
you can check the explanation here
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Hey Cristian, many thanks for your reply! I just tried that out, but unfortunately, that still won't work for the deleting function (I added a `console.log()` to see when it fires, and it only fires when adding ingredients). Do you have any idea why that could be?

Comment: ahh ok ok, try with presentIngredients.length as dependency

Comment: but now work with add, right?

Comment: The solution is the answer above, many thanks for your help anyway Cristian!